# SAS scan variable's label and then change the variable's value

Tags: arrays, variables, sas, macros

Good morning!

I have a situation that needs some help.

I have a dataset with 300 variables, almost all of them are numeric var. The data source is an Excel spreadsheet. About 100 variables in the spreadsheet are something like "Percent of ...." or "... percent ...".

But the value is not decimal, instead, is a numeric value after multiple by 100. I need to change the value to a decimal. For example, the value now in the dataset is 53, but actually, it is 0.53.

My thinking is to first scan the variable's label if there is "Percent" or "percent" in there, if so, store this variable in an array. Then have a do loop to read the array and change the corresponding value by being divided by 100.

I did the codes as the following:

```
 proc contents data=dataset1 noprint out=__cont;
   run;

   proc sql;
    select count(libname) into: maxcount
    from __cont
    ;
   quit;

   %put &maxcount;

   data output;
    set __cont;
    array percentvar{&maxcount} $;
    do i=1 to &maxcount;
        if scan(upcase(label), 'PERCENT')>1 then percentvar(i)=name;
    end;
    drop i;
   run;
```

But actually, the array has a dynamic dimension. This is the first error, then I am not sure how to connect the variable with the array and then change its value.

I need help! or some logic clarification.

Thank you so much for any input and thoughts!

Appreciated!
Lin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for code generation for this project. You can use the VLABEL() function to find the label.

```
data output;
  set dataset1 ;
  array nums _numeric_;
  do index=1 to dim(nums);
    if findw(vlabel(nums[index]),'percent',,'i') then 
      nums[index]=nums[index]/100 
    ;
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank you so much for the coding! Somehow, the value doesn't change to be as decimal. I am still looking at it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Make sure you haven't attached a FORMAT that does not display decimal places. You might want to just remove all formats. `format _numeric_;`  Make sure to re-attach formats to to any DATE or DATETIME variables.  Make sure it is the LABEL that you need check and not the NAME of the variable.

Comment: I remove all formats for numeric variables and still not decimal. Then I use Freeman's code (refer below) "if index(upcase(vlabel(nums[index])), 'PERCENT') > 0 then nums[index]=nums[index] / 100; " it works. I am not sure the reason yet. I will take a look at it later.

Comment: If just depends on what you want to search for. The difference is that INDEX() or FIND() just looks for strings and INDEXW() and FINDW() look for words.  So if the string PERCENT in the label is not separated from the other characters by one of the delimiter characters you listed third argument then it will not match.  For example if the label had PERCENTAGE instead of PERCENT then looking a WORD would not find it.